# How to reverse a css transistion on scroll for fly in / fly out effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get an fly-in / fly- out effect happening

Scroll down - animate in

Scroll-up animate out

To get a similar effect to the nizo website

http://nizoapp.com/

I have used this code I found on Stackoverflow "Fade in element on scroll down using css"
to determine whether the element is on screen, in the viewport, and then animate it.

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.article').each(function (i) {

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

                $(this).animate({
                    'opacity': '1'
                }, 500);

            }

        });

    });
```

Which works quite well.

I have added it to this demo page, and modified it.

http://saigonhousefinder.com/potteryone/fadinonscroll.html

(probably not live for long)

I have used css transitions to get the effect I am looking for. FLy-in Fly-out etc etc

And then I found..... this function which does the same thing

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

Anyway.......

I cant get the animations to work when scrolling down, fly-in.

But I cannot get the animations to go in reverse when they fly out on scroll up

I thought the easiest way would be to detect if you are scrolling down of up,  so I found this method / function

```
(function () {
    var previousScroll = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
       var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (currentScroll > previousScroll){



  $("#div").fadeIn("slow");
       }
       else {

  $("#div").fadeOut("slow");



       }
       previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
}());
```

Which works well, but I cannot get it working.

At this point I can detect when an element is visible on the screen then add an effect to it.

What I need it to detect when that same element is beginning to go off the screen and apply another effect to it.

Any help on how to get this working would be great

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

That's a really neat demo and a great concept! I played around with some code and it seems that you are almost there. You need to detect when the top of the screen meets the top of the element, so only calculate the offset once when the page is loaded. I added a 20px threshold so it kicks in a bit early. Let me know if this helps, it can be tweaked depending on how and when you want to call it. Here is a simple js fiddle demo
http://jsfiddle.net/XhAhR/23/

```
(function () {

  var previousScroll = 0;
  var elemTop = $("#div").offset().top;
  $("#div").fadeOut();

  $(window).scroll(function () {
   var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

   if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
           if(elemTop -20 > currentScroll){
               $("#div").fadeIn("slow");
           }
   }
   else {
       if(elemTop - 20 > currentScroll){
           $("#div").fadeOut("slow");
       }
   }
   previousScroll = currentScroll;
  });
}());
```

Comment: Hi there great work I have been trying to modify your jsfiddle so that the fade in fade out effect starts from the bottom of the screen, so that as each would div would fade in as it entered the screen and fade out as it left I know I need to use the $(window).height; function but I cannot get it to work. Any help would be great, here is your fiddle with more divs cheers http://jsfiddle.net/mrcharis/73Qcs/1/